# После размещения react-native приложения в Play Market перестала работать аутентификация Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: firebase, react-native, аутентификация, google-play-console, firebase-android

Мое приложение использует для аутентификации Firebase Phone Auth. Во время тестирования как c отладочным ключом SHA-1, так и с релизным все работало хорошо.
После загрузки и размещения aab в Google Play Console я, следуя документации, поменял в Firebase релизный ключ SHA-1 на ключ, взятый из Google Play Console (Сертификат ключа подписи приложения). После этого аутентификация перестала нормально работать.

1. После отправки номер телефона на проверку рекапча не появляется, но секунд через 7 приходит смс с кодом
2. Когда полученный код вводишь в поле для проверки, код всегда невалидный
3. Я прикрутил Крашлитикс и выяснил, что код всегда приходит уже устаревшим

   [auth/session-expired] The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.
4. В момент получения кода в консоли Firebase номер отображается как зарегистрированный.
5. При всем этом если ввести на одном устройстве номер телефона другого устройства, то полученный там код валидацию пройдет.
6. Аутентификация на iOS работает без проблем. Эта ошибка только на Android. И связываю я ее со сменой ключей SHA-1. Но возможно, я ошибаюсь.
7. Я уже обращался за помощью в саппорт Firebase. Ничего толкового они мне не подсказали, хотя долго пытались решить мою проблему (за что им спасибо).

Может, кто сталкивался с подобным, пожалуйста, помогите. Уже третью ночь пытаюсь это разрулить.